# code interchanges

Tags: java

which is equivalent in java to "exit(0)" in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.exit(0)
just do it

Answer (score 11):

`System.exit(0)`

Comment: Damn, you were faster ... but I added the links ;-)

Comment: Rack it. There is no such thing as `exit()` "in C". `exit()` is a system call. You can use the system call from any language capable of linking to it. Please try not to be one of thse C coders who thinks the whole operating system is part of the C language.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz: Lol. That has to be one of my favorite comments ever.